# datepicker dateranges overrides layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to highlight multiple dateranges in jquery datepicker. So far it's working with a single range. But when I try to show multiple dateranges, the for-loop overrides the previous layout.

Using the following code:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({

    firstDay: 1,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {

        for(var i = 0; i < testJson.length; i++) {
            startDate = new Date(testJson[i].startDate);
            endDate = new Date(testJson[i].endDate);

            if(date.getTime() === endDate.getTime()) {
                return [true, 'start-of-day', 'Begin van dag gereserveerd!'];
            }

            if(date.getTime() === startDate.getTime()) {
                return [true, 'end-of-day', 'Einde van dag gereserveerd!'];
            }

            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate) {
                return [true, 'full-day', 'Gereserveerd!'];
            }

        }
        return [true, '', ''];
    }
});
```

I'm getting the current situation:

[image: Current situation]

Desired situation:

Currently it only shows half a day when 2 ranges follow eachother up. What I want is when a start and end-date are on the same date, it shows a full day.

If any other information is required, please ask. New to this.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

This is an example of the json i'm getting

```
var testJson = [{
    "startDate": "2015, 5, 1",
        "endDate": "2015, 5, 4"
}, {
    "startDate": "2015, 5, 4",
        "endDate": "2015, 5, 11"
}];
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the accepted answer it works perfectly as shown below (and demonstrated in the fiddle of the accepted answer:

```
var testJson = [
    {
        "startDate": "2015, 6, 8",
        "endDate": "2015, 6, 15"
    },
    {
        "startDate": "2015, 6, 15",
        "endDate": "2015, 6, 22"
    },
    {
        "startDate": "2015, 6, 22",
        "endDate": "2015, 6, 29"
    }
];
```

The only thing to keep in mind is to keep the records in **ascending** order according to the startdate. The rest works out perfectly, because the records are supplied without overlapping.

[image: Result]

Comment: Can you set up a working example ? (including the css and the json)

Comment: @empiric Just posted an example of the json. Can't get the fiddle to work just yet.

Comment: can you add your css too? [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a5y69mye/) is a working fiddle

Comment: One thing I noticed: You adding the class `start-of-day` inside the condition which is met with `endDate.getTime()`. Shouldn't it be `end-of-day` at this line ? [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a5y69mye/1/)

Comment: @empiric A range ends in the morning. So endDate occupies the start-of-day.

Comment: @empiric The css for the half days are background images, so the css from your last demo will have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give it a try:

```
if(testJson[i+1]){
     nextStartDate = new Date(testJson[i+1].startDate);
}
if (date.getTime() === endDate.getTime() && date.getTime() === nextStartDate.getTime()) {
     return [true, 'full-day', 'Gereserveerd!'];
}
```

1. Save the next Start-Date of there is one
2. Check if the current date is the same is the current endDate and the next startDate, if so it return it as a full day

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a5y69mye/2/)**